# Guzzle: Changing request options in a pool generator

Tags: php, curl, guzzle6, guzzle

I've got the following code:

```
$generator = function() use ($headers) {
   while ($request = array_shift($this->requests)) {
      yield 'id_' . $request['id'] => new Request('GET', $request['url'], $headers);
   }
}
```

However, I'd like to add some custom request options such as a proxy and custom timeout. As far as I know, these can only be set when the client actually sends;

```
   $this->client->send($r, ['proxy' => $proxy, 'connect_timeout' => 10]);
```

When I adjust the generator as follows:

```
   $r = new Request('GET', $request['url'], $headers);

   yield 'id_' . $request['id'] => $this->client->send($r, ['proxy' => $proxy, 'connect_timeout' => 10]);
```

The code is no longer working because it is expecting a RequestInterface.

So how can I set the proxy in a pool generator instead? Is it not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generator can return either a RequestInterface or a PromiseInterface.

So you able to do a "full" request, just do it asynchronously to immediately get a promise and yield it to the pool.

```
$generator = function () use ($hreaders) {
    while ($request = array_shift($this->requests)) {
        yield 'id_' . $request['id'] => $this->client->sendAsync('GET', $request['url'], [
            // Your options here.
        ]);
    }
};
```